# File upload form in custom admin module

Tags: php, magento-2.1.7

I'm creating a custom admin module in which i need a form to upload a csv file
Here is the code:
Controller file:
    app/code/Importa/Import/Controller/Adminhtml/Import/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Importa\Import\Controller\Adminhtml\Import;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;


class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action{
protected $resultPageFactory;
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {        
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute(){
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;
}
}
?>
```

Layout file:

app/code/Importa/Import/view/adminhtml/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
<head>
        <title>
            Importa
        </title>
        </head>
         <body>

 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="Importa" template="Importa_Import::sample/importa.phtml" />
     </referenceContainer> 
    </body>       
</page>
```

Template file:

```
app/code/Importa/Import/view/adminhtml/templates/sample

<form action="" method=post enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>Seleziona file</p> <br>
<input type=file name=userfile>  <br>
<input type=submit value=Invia name=conferma>
</form>
```

The problem is that i don't know what the action url to refer the template to the index.php file.

Comment: You need to Upload File? please specify issue .

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify app/code/Importa/Import/view/adminhtml/layout/import_index_inde.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
<head>
        <title>
            Importa
        </title>
        </head>
         <body>

 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="Importa" template="Importa_Import::sample/importa.phtml" />
     </referenceContainer> 
    </body>       
</page>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">  
<head>
        <title>
            Importa
        </title>
        </head>
         <body>

 <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="\Magento\Backend\Block\Template" name="Importa" template="Importa_Import::sample/importa.phtml" />
     </referenceContainer> 
    </body>       
</page>
```